# What is the basic TN for Character Rolls in Mass Battles?

Tags: savage-worlds

When a character chooses to fight in a Mass Battle. What is the original TN (before the mods for number of tokens and character rank).

For a spellcraft roll is we assume TN 4 but for fighting it is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target number is 4, which represents the abstract nature of a 'round' in mass battles - see [here](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18290&highlight=mass%20battle) for the official answer.